# rails 4 simple_form check_boxes collection foiled by strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm unable to get my form to work.

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blasts, foreign_key: "author_id"
end

class Blast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  validates :author_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  # validates :recipients, presence: true

  [edit]
  before_validation :add_recipients

  private
  def add_recipients
    array = self.recipients
    self.recipients = ""
    array.each do |initials|
      self.recipients += "#{initials}, " unless initials.blank?
    end
    self.recipients = self.recipients[0..-3]
  end
  [end edit]
end
```

**Blast Controller**

```
class BlastController < ApplicationController

def new
  @blast = current_user.blasts.new
end

def create
  @blast = current_user.blasts.build(blast_params)

  if @blast.save
    flash[:success] = "Blast sent!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end

private

  def blast_params
    params.require(:blast).permit(:content, :recipients)
  end
end
```

**Views**

*app/views/blasts/new.html.erb*

```
 <%= render 'shared/blast_form' %>
```

*app/views/shared/_blast_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for @blast do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.input :content, placeholder: "Compose new blast..." %>
  <%= f.input :recipients, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.all(order: 'last_name'), label_method: :full_name, value_method: :initials, include_hidden: false %>
  <%= f.submit "Send Blast", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This code allows me to create a blast but the recipients are nil.  When I uncomment the Blast validation for recipients presence, the new blast isn't saved and produces the error: "Recipients can't be blank."  My debug hash shows that initials have been submitted, though:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters  
utf8: "✓" 
authenticity_token: B/s22B5hrFrncxZkEUQdw2SJfpHm0qFpV2SUFg9jFR0= 
blast: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters    
content: Hello world!   
recipients:
  - JC
  - AC
  - ''  
commit: Send Blast  
action: create  
controller: blasts
```

I'd be super grateful if anyone has any ideas.  This seems like it should be pretty strait forward.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try giving `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` in your `blast` model and change the strong parameters as `params.require(:blast).permit(:content, :recipients,user_attributes: [:id,:last_name,full_name,...])`

Comment: Hurray, @Pavan!  You got me on the path to find a solution.  I added (slight variation of your) `accepts_nested_attributes_for :author` to `Blast model` and made the strong parameters: `params.require(:blast).permit(:content, recipients: [])`.  I then added a rather inelegant `before_validation` `add_recipients` method to the `Blast` model to convert the recipients array to a string (see edit to my question above.)  If you combine your suggestion and my implementation into an answer I will accept it.  I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :author` to Blast model and have a before_validation like this

```
class Blast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author


  before_validation :add_recipients

  private
  def add_recipients
    array = self.recipients
    self.recipients = ""
    array.each do |initials|
      self.recipients += "#{initials}, " unless initials.blank?
    end
    self.recipients = self.recipients[0..-3]
  end

end
```

And also,make the strong parameters as like this

```
def blast_params
params.require(:blast).permit(:content, recipients: [])
end
```